# Where does the limitation to 100 connections to docker.socket (using aiodocker) come from?

Tags: python, docker, sockets, aiodocker

I'm using the Python-package [aiodocker](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiodocker) do monitor running Docker containers using `container.stats()` like this:

```
async for stats in container.stats():
    do_something(...)
```

And this works as expected.

`lsof +E /run/docker.sock` (might also be `/var/run/docker.sock`) reveals that there will be a connection to `/run/docker.sock` established for every monitored container - which is not a surprise, `docker stats` would also use one connection per container.

However, using Python / `aiodocker` I can establish a maximum of 100 connections per process - after that new calls involving a new connection will block.

Running another instance of the same Python script seems to be not affected by the first one (but can also open a maximum of 100 connections).

Strangely `docker stats` does not seem to have this limitation - it will happily monitor 200 and more containers.

Searching through the [aiodocker source code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiodocker/tree/master/aiodocker) does not show any hard coded limitation like this, and using DDG/Google/ChatGPT I can't find any reference to a limitation to 100 connections/process.

Where is this limitation defined? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aiodocker` uses `aiohttp`. `aiohttp` defaults to a connection limit of 100.

`aiohttp` creates a client using [`ClientSession`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession) which in turn uses a default [`BaseConnector`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.BaseConnector).

In the docs, you'll see the limit argument on the BaseConnector says:

*limit (int) – total number simultaneous connections. If limit is None the connector has no limit (default: 100).*

You can pass in a custom connector. But in this case you also have to define `url`. On a Linux system the following function returns a `Docker()` instance with customizable file limit:

```
def docker_connection(limit: int = 100) -> Docker:
    """Creates a Docker connection with a customized Connector in order to
    increase connection limit"""
    for sockpath in [Path("/run/docker.sock"), Path("/var/run/docker.sock")]:
        if sockpath.is_socket():
            return Docker(
                "unix://localhost",
                aiohttp.UnixConnector(sockpath.as_posix(), limit=limit))
    raise RuntimeError("No path to docker.sock found")

# to be used like this:
async with docker_connection(limit=256) as self.docker_client:
    ...
```

Documentation on `aiodocker` client function signature + `aiohttp` client:

https://aiodocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html